# jQuery-UI, arcplan and requireJs: Datepicker won't show

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, requirejs

I use the BI software arcplan (8.6.1). This application does not host a datepicker. Thus I integrated jQuery-UI by just adding the line  to the main-page so it always loads. arcplan, among other libraries, uses requireJS and jQuery. I cannot edit much of the DOM as it is provided by arcplan itself.
Until a recent HTML5-framework-update by arcplan to jQuery 2.1.4 the datepicker (with jQuery-UI 1.10.4) all worked fine. Now, all the datepicker does is adding one line to the end of the DOM:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
```

When updating to jQuery-UI 1.11.4 however, a different error occurs. The Chrome console throws the following line (from my custom scripts.js-File, also loaded inside the main page without requireJS):

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
```

Succeeded by a requireJS error:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (e){function t(t,s){var n,a,o,r=t.nodeName.toLowerCase();return"area"===r[...]
```

I assume I might find a solution by updating to jQuery-UI 1.11.4. 
Interestingly, the tooltip plugin (1.10.4) works like charm.

This is how I call the datepicker:

```
//just a plain tobj.datepicker(); won't work either.
    tobj.datepicker({
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
                firstDay: 1,
                regional: sprache,
                changeMonth: true,
                showWeek: true, 
                minDate: miniDat,
                maxDate: maxiDat,
                onClose: function () 
                                    {
                                        tobj.remove();
                                    }
            });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, now I found the mistake.
The tobj was created like this:

```
    $('<input type="text"  id="dummy_'+objekt+'" name="dummy_'+objekt+'" disabled>').appendTo("body");

var tobj = $('#dummy_'+objekt+'');
```

And since jQuery 2.1.4 it seems the disabled tag didn't work anymore.
So I changed it to

```
    $('<input type="text"  id="dummy_'+objekt+'" name="dummy_'+objekt+'" readonly="readonly">').appendTo("body");

var tobj = $('#dummy_'+objekt+'');
```

and it worked.